# Unable to change owner of external drive

Tags: permissions, mount

I have an external drive mounted at `/mnt/xbox`:
[image]

However I cannot change the permissions of a folder.

```
hutber@hutber:/mnt/xbox$ ll
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root         144 Aug 10 12:05  Linux/
hutber@hutber:/mnt/xbox$ sudo chown -R hutber:hutber Linux/
hutber@hutber:/mnt/xbox$ ll
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root         144 Aug 10 12:05  Linux/
```

How can I take ownership of this drive?

Comment: With Windows file systems Linux will set ownership and permissions at mount, and it cannot be changed. But you can unmount and mount again with other permissions. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072).

Comment: Thanks very much. I wonder if we should either mark this as a duplicate or `nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,rw,uid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117` add a answer for it? The above worked, :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) If you wish, you can 'answer your own question' and link for more details to my answer (the link in my comment above), if you wish I can write that answer, and if you wish I can vote for marking your question as a duplicate. You decide :-)